# Problem with regexp trailing space

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, liquid

I'm currently modifying Liquid Framework (http://github.com/tobi/liquid) in order to make it support literals.

It's all nice and cool but I'm having a slight problem with the regexp I'm using. The following works great, except the fact that it captures the trailing space in $1

```
"{{{gnomeslab }}}" =~ /^(?:{{{\s?)(.*)(?:}}})$/
```

Puts the following value in $1

```
"gnomeslab "
```

In order to avoid the temptation of using a right trim, it would awesome if someone from StackOverflow could give me a hand with this patch ;)

Best regards,
DBA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/^(?:{{{\s*)(.*?)(?:\s*}}})$/
```

Comment: Thanks LukeH. You officially saved Liquid literals from a trim ;)